# Position relative element in front of absolute element CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck in a problem, I want to show the relative element in front of absolute element, I know z-index don't work with relative elements. How can I show the image in front of the strip.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9EEv/9/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Teset</title>
<style>
.container {
      width: 1170px;margin:auto
      }
      .footer-elements{text-align:center;bottom:0;height:15em}
      .footer-elements .content-b{text-align:center;position:relative;height:10em}
      .footer-elements .content-b img.main-img{text-align:center;width:18em;margin-top:-3em}
      .footer-elements .content-b .strip-m{background:#231F20;height:9em;}
      .footer-elements .content-b .strip-border{width:100%;height:1.3em;position:absolute;top:0;left:0%;background-size:auto 100%;
      background:url(http://i666.photobucket.com/albums/vv22/SincerelyBerry/HAIJYNX/backgrounds/stripes.png) repeat-x;}
</style>
      </head>
      <body>

          <!-- container Start -->
          <div class="container">
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                  <div class="footer-elements">
                        <div class="content-b">
                            <div class="strip-m row">
                                <div class="strip-border"></div>
                                <img src="http://i252.photobucket.com/albums/hh15/liveyourlife815/stripes-1.png" class="main-img" alt="footer">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
      </body>
    </html>
http://jsfiddle.net/Q9EEv/9/
```

Absolute element is strip so I want it on back on that relative image.

Thanks

Comment: z-index does work on position:relative; elements

Comment: it will work for `relative,absolute,fixed`. But not work in case of `static`

Comment: The headache you must have at least once: MDN **[Understanding z-index - the stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)** ^^ EDIT: cure from headache may come from **[testing it live](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/z-index/teach_yourself_how_elements_stack.asp)**, thanks to tjk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9EEv/10/

```
.content-b img
{
    position: relative;
}
```

You solved it your self. But z-index does work on every positioned element (not static).